# need help to configure eclipse-php-helios-win32

Tags: php, eclipse, configuration

I have downloaded `eclipse-php-helios-win32.zip` but it doesn't run the php file, what is the extra setting I've got to do?

I am using WAMP5 and I've created my workspace into www folder inside the WAMP

When I try to run it it doesn't run my php page as well as doesn't give me any message or error.

When I'm trying to test debugger then it gives me error that it doesn't find `dummy.php` file.

What is it I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse doesn't contain a PHP runtime.  You need to install PHP on your machine as well.  Once you've don that, configure Eclipse to use the installed PHP executable to run PHP scripts in CLI mode.

Getting them to run in web server mode is a bit more involved, but the way I've got it set up on my machine is that the eclipse workspace is in a directory accessible by the web server, and I just run the scripts in my browser.

Comment: that is i've to manually run it? it will not run my php page by pressing ctrl+f11 ?

Comment: It probably can be done but I never tried settign it up.  Just running it in the browser seemed a lot easier and once you've got xdebug or zend debugger installed you can still debug the script in Eclipse anyway.